# Read configuration file and assagin it into script variables

Tags: linux, bash, shell, script, environment-variables

**I need to read a configuration file and assign into script variables and omit commented lines,**

Sample configuration file:

```
# This is sample configuration file
SRV_IP=192.168.1.12
DB_IP=192.168.1.10
DB_PORT=3306
```

I need to read this configuration file and get into a shell script.

Like below

Script example

```
#!/bin/bash

echo " Reading configuration file $1 "

echo " Server IP = $SRV_IP
    Database IP = $DB_IP
    Database Port = $DB_PORT"
```

After execution of the above script output like this:

> ./read_conf.sh sample.conf

Output is like below

> ```
> Server IP = 192.168.1.12
> Database IP = 192.168.1.10
> Database Port = 3306
> ```

After executing the script inside current shell or within the script each variable have values specified in configuration file $SRV_IP have the value 192.168.1.12 without using shell builtin command source.

**Whenever use variables inside the script it must be have the values specified int the configuration file.**

Comment: Crossposting: http://stackoverflow.com/q/33455992/3776858

Comment: Insert a new line after first echo line with `. "$1"`.

Comment: It's uses the builtin feature i want to skip this, and make it normal way via parsing the file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using a below script made it.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo " Reading configuration file $1 "

conf_file=$1

while IFS= read -r line; do
  line=${line%%#*}
  case $line in
    *=*)
      var=${line%%=*}
      case $var in
        *[!A-Z_a-z]*)
          echo "Warning: invalid variable name $var ignored" >&2
          continue;;
      esac
      if eval '[ -n "${'$var'+1}" ]'; then
        echo "Warning: variable $var already set, redefinition ignored" >&2
        continue
      fi
      line=${line#*=}
      eval $var='"$line"'
  esac
done <"$conf_file"

echo "Current values after reading configuration file"

echo " Server IP = $SRV_IP
    Database IP = $DB_IP
    Database Port = $DB_PORT"

exit 0
```